# Api call on checkbox click not called multiple times on multiple clicks

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have multiple checkboxes and onChange event, I call the same API for all these checkboxes. After I get the result from the API, I call another API to refresh my list which depends on the previous API I called. The problem is that if I click the checkboxes slowly, it functions fine. But if I click the checkboxes fast, some of the calls don't go through and update never happens. How can I resolve this issue?

```
OnChangeUpdateList(productID, e) {
    var flag = e.target.checked;
    this.Service.updateProductCompareList(productID, flag).subscribe(
        result => {
            this.GetList();
            this.RefreshCheckBoxStatus(productID);
        },
        error => { alert(error); },
        () => {

        }

    );
}
```

Comment: I am using Angular 2.

Comment: I guess it might be a cache issue you need to append one random number  or append datetiem stamp to your API  so that it will considered as new request every time and will send to server like "User/GetDetails" + Math.random()

Comment: I am sending unique id based on check box clicked as a parameter.

Comment: can u provide HTML sample?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" [id]="item.Document.id"  [checked]="RefreshCheckBoxStatus(item.Document.id)" (change)="OnChangeUpdateProductCompareList(item.Document.id, $event)" (click)="onCompareClick($event)" />

Comment: The checkboxes are rendered in          <div *ngFor="#item of Results">
and each checkbox has a unique value for id item.Document.id

Comment: In my sample i am not able to repo your mentioned issue. Plz check sample and also observe console window and Network window of browser http://plnkr.co/edit/p35RatDnN52yidjeYvvX?p=preview I can see multiple ajax call when i check/uncheck checkbox